# How to add simple fade in effect on element that's lazy loaded with js

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this lazy loading script to load in more posts with .load. How can I add an animation effect–for example show('slow')–when the js loads in each post so each post fades in when it loads?

My JS:

```
    jQuery(function(){
    var page = 2;
    var myurl = blogUrll
    var loadmore = 'on';
    jQuery(document).on('scroll resize', function() {
      if (jQuery(window).scrollTop() + jQuery(window).height() + 200 > jQuery(document).height()) {
        if (loadmore == 'on') {
          loadmore = 'off';
          jQuery('#spinner').css('visibility', 'visible');
          jQuery('#lazyload').append(jQuery('<div class="blog-grid" id="p' + page + '">').load(myurl + '/blog/page/' + page + ' article', function() {
            page++;
            loadmore = 'on';
            jQuery('#spinner').css('visibility', 'hidden');
          }));
        }
      }
    });
    jQuery( document ).ajaxComplete(function( event, xhr, options ) {
        if ( $(".blog-grid").is(':empty'))
        {
           loadmore = 'off';
        }
      if (xhr.responseText.indexOf('class="blog-grid"') == -1) {
      }
    });
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For each of your blog posts:

```
<div class="blogPost"> ... </div>
```

Set it to be initially non-opaque:

```
.blogPost {
    opacity: 0;
}
```

And use the jQuery `animate()` on the callback (in your `ajaxComplete()`) after you load the blog post to make it opaque.

```
$(".blogPost").animate({opacity: 1}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `style` attribute at appended `.blog-grid` element `opacity` to `0` , calling `$(this).fadeTo("slow", 1)` at `.load()` `complete` function

```
jQuery('#lazyload')
.append(
  jQuery('<div style="opacity:0" class="blog-grid" id="p' + page + '">')
  .load(myurl + '/blog/page/' + page + ' article', function() {
    $(this).fadeTo("slow", 1);
    page++;
    loadmore = 'on';
    jQuery('#spinner').css('visibility', 'hidden');
  })
);
```